# Unsure how to iterate through two arrays in erb?

Tags: ruby, erb

I am new to ruby and erb. I am trying to iterate through two arrays. I want to print the message details and user details that match but so far I just get 'name1 name123' printed next to each message which is wrong. Any help would be appreciated,thank you?

name1 name123

message1
2022-06-08 12:00:00 name1 name123

message2
2022-09-07 13:00:00 name1 name123

message3
2022-08-06 15:00:00 name1 name123

message4
2022-10-08 13:48:00

```
<html>
        <body>
        <h1>Peeps</h1>
            <%@peeps.each do |peep|%>
            <%@users.find do |user|%>
            <% user.id == peep.user_id%>
            <%= user.name%> <%= user.username %></br></br>
              
            <%=peep.message%> </br><%=peep.time_stamp%>
           
            <%end%>
            <%end%>
        </body>
    
    
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Is Peep a model, if so, what's the relation between Peep and User? Perhaps this can be done in a different way

Comment: yes peep is a model. The user_id is a foreign key on the peep table. each user with have one or many peeps.  Peeps and users are stored as arrays

Answer (score 3):

You can get rid of the inner loop on `@users` if you split the operation by parts - first by selecting every peep belonging to any of the users in `@users`, then doing the printing;

```
user_ids = @users.map(&:id)
@peeps
  .select { |peep| user_ids.include?(peep.user_id) }
  .each do |peep|
    user = @users.find { |user| user.id == peep.user_id }

    # Here you get access to peep and user
  end
```

Comment: Sorry, I am a little confused. I am just using plain ruby not rails. I am unfamilar with '.pluck etc'

Comment: Ok, my fault. I thought it was Rails as we were speaking about models. See the updated answer then.